# Why can't this command be executed?

Tags: linux, unix

When I try to execute `ls|more`, the command works perfectly, however when I try to save the command in a variable like `x='ls|more'` and then execute it using `$x` I get the following error :

> ls: cannot access |: No such file or directory
>   ls: cannot access more: No such file or directory

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you execute

```
ls|more
```

the shell parses that line and understands the three tokens to be the command `ls` followed by a pipe, followed by the command `more`. When you execute

```
$x
```

the shell expands that variable but does not parse the result, at least not in the same way. It will split the contents of the variable at white space, take the first sequence of characters to be a command name, and the following sequences of characters to be arguments. So it will understand `ls|more` to be the command `ls|more` and `ls | more` to be the command `ls` followed by the arguments `|` and `more`, which `ls` takes to be file names.

To get the shell to reparse the contents of that variable, use `eval`, like this:

```
eval "$x"
```

Comment: While you were accepting my answer, I was editing it to try to do a better job of answering "Why?"

Comment: Shouldn't the argument to eval be quoted? Note, that variables can contain any characters including newlines and word-splitting before eval would change meaning in such cases.

Comment: @JanHudec: I think you're right. Thank you. I edited my answer to add the quotes.